# How can I make Arabic letters in the terminal display correctly?

Tags: language-support, arabic

Arabic letters in the terminal look different than what they are supposed to be, and are not readable. Arabic characters in a word should be connected, but in this case, they are scattered in an unreadable manner.

How can I make my terminal display Arabic correctly?

[image: Broken Arabic in a terminal]

Comment: Currently, the Gnome emulator [doesn't support](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vte/+bug/263822) RTL languages. You can try visiting the bug report, and see if you can find any workaround. You can also try the following answer as a current workaround: https://askubuntu.com/a/81151/8698